# Is there a function for knowing if user is 'shop_manager' in WP / woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to know if the shop_manager is logged-in WP/woocommerce. I know the function is_admin(), but do you know a way to use something like this 'is_shop_manager()' ?

Thanks

Comment: is_admin() will also return true for shopmanager, not only admin. This function is asking if it is in admin area which is also accessible by shop manager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not any direct inbuilt function as shop_manager role is coming from WooCommerce & not from WordPress, but it can be achieved with following code:

```
function is_shop_manager() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( isset( $user['roles'][0] ) && $user['roles'][0] == 'shop_manager' ) {
        return true;    // when user is shop manager
    } else {
        return false;   // when user is not shop manager
    }
}

if ( is_shop_manager() ) {
    // write code for shop_manager here
}
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: It works indeed, but I think @Anfelipe's answer is neater.

Answer (score 23):

Actually Yes, there is!

```
current_user_can( 'manage_woocommerce' );
```

Docs:

[current_user_can($capability)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can)

['manage_woocommerce'](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/roles-capabilities/)

Comment: this check will return true for both admin and shopadmin. As admin has this cabability. I tested it.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed code:

```
function is_shop_manager() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( isset( $user->roles[0] ) && $user->roles[0] == 'shop_manager' ) {
        return true;    // when user is shop manager
    } else {
        return false;   // when user is not shop manager
    }
}
```